vs code nuxt 3 doesn't highlight error in <template>
I use nuxt 3 when I put a variable that does not exist, it does not show me that it is an error,
I use VS code


The extension I have for Vue:

I also have ESLint extension
I downloaded @nuxt/eslint but it still doesn't show the error,
Is there a way to solve this problem? A specific addition or something specific to do,
package.json :
{
  "name": "nuxt-app",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxt/eslint": "^0.3.10",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.5.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "nuxt": "^3.11.2",
    "pinia": "^2.1.7",
    "vue": "^3.4.21",
    "vue-router": "^4.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/i18n": "^8.3.0",
    "sass": "^1.75.0"
  }
}


eslint.config.mjs :
// @ts-check
import withNuxt from './.nuxt/eslint.config.mjs'

export default withNuxt(
  // Your custom configs here
)


tsconfig.json :
{
  // https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/typescript
  "extends": "./.nuxt/tsconfig.json"
}



Do you have the ESlint VScode extension installed?

yup i have ESlint

Have you configured it as your linter in VScode?

how to do this?
